# А что, собственно, такое "закорки"?

Tags: этимология

Прочитал вопрос об ударении в слове "закорки". Да, это плечи, куда сажают маленьких детей. Но откуда такое название?

Comment: Об этом слове и родственных ему есть интересное исследование в книге Мокиенко "Образы русской речи"

Answer (score 3):

Этимология слова ЗАКОРКИ:
 а)по словарю Брокгауза и Эфрона:верхняя часть спины; заплечье.
Др.-русск. корки - плечи, спина;

б)по этимологическому словарю Крылова: это существительное, имеющее значение "верхняя часть спины", по всей вероятности, образовано с помощью приставки от исчезнувшего корки – "плечи, спина" (легшего в основу глагола корчиться – "гнуться, сгибаться").

Comment: Допустим,  было  некогда  слово  "корки" со  значением  плечи, спина.  Почему  именно  оно  должно  было  лечь  в  основу  глагола  "корчится" ?  А  рожи  корчить ?